# Oracle Archiving and deleting billions of records

Tags: database, oracle

There is a base with 2 namespaces (main and archive) located on the same disk space.

Task: transfer records up to a certain time of creation (the date is present in one of the tables) in the archive space in an identical table. (Oracle 12c) (hundreds of billions of rows in each table)

Because this will work on the production, the option of transferring only the necessary records to a new table is not suitable, because the data will be updated in the process. (will be executed SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE from same table of main namespace)

Currently the best option which I found:

```
CREATE TABLE MAIN_NAME_SPACE.TEMP AS SELECT ID FROM MAIN_NAME_SPACE.MAIN_TABLE
```

create a temp table with id for some period (~ 5 days) (as a separate procedure);

```
PROCEDURE ARCH AS
  table variable;
BEGIN

  SELECT ID INTO table FROM TEMP;

  FORALL i IN table
    DELETE ARCH_NAME_SPACE.TABLE_1 T WHERE T.ID = i;

  FORALL i IN table
    INSERT INTO ARCH_NAME_SPACE.TABLE_1 VALUES(SELECT * FROM MAIN_NAME_SPACE.TABLE_1 T WHERE T.ID = i);

...

  FORALL i IN table
    DELETE ARCH_NAME_SPACE.TABLE_N T WHERE T.ID = i;

  FORALL i IN table
    INSERT INTO ARCH_NAME_SPACE.TABLE_N VALUES(SELECT * FROM MAIN_NAME_SPACE.TABLE_N T WHERE T.ID = i);

END ARCH;
```

we read the data in a table variable and for each table in the archive through FORALL we delete the records (if they exist there) and write in a new one;

```
PROCEDURE DELETE AS
  table variable;
BEGIN

  SELECT ID INTO table FROM TEMP;

  FORALL i IN table
    DELETE MAIN_NAME_SPACE.TABLE_1 T WHERE T.ID = i;

...

  FORALL i IN table
    DELETE MAIN_NAME_SPACE.TABLE_N T WHERE T.ID = i;

END ARCH;
```

Using another procedure, we delete data from the main namespace by analogy (leaving this piece within the same procedure, the time increases to 2.5 hours for unknown reasons).

But the speed leaves much to be desired (10 million records are transferred to the archive for 43 minutes, removal from the original namespace is 1h 5min).

Is there any other way to speed up this pleasure? (earlier, before updating to 12c, all this worked through the cursor veryyyyyyy slowly and veryyyyyyy rarely started).

P.S.: tables are not partitioned.

Also maybe somebody can say why with INVISIBLE indexes DELETE/INSERT operations work faster? I'am not understand how it works.

Thank u advance.

Comment: Does it work faster to copy the whole table then delete newer records? Obviously only relevant assuming this is a somewhat one-off excercise. In mssql you can join tables from different databases and use 'where id is null' to dictate what rows to copy/delete

Comment: LJ01 table size is 1Tb, apparently it will take the same time